# set permission on infopath views base on sharepoint groups

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-server, groups

I've customized my newitem.aspx of my list with infoPath in share point 2010 with 4 views and now I want to set permission on each view base on share point groups
how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly doing things the hard way. (Then again, I don't know your unique requirements.) Permissions should be placed on content (sites, libraries, lists, etc.). Views are generally sub-sets of content, not pages. Changing view permissions on content will not change the content permissions. Simpler, if you must do this, to make 4 pages (with views, web parts [which may be CEWP] or whatever) and manage permissions to the pages.  It's easier (less hassle) to manage permissions on sites, libraries, and lists. (Pages are rather like views, if you use JSON/JS queries.) Permissions management can become a large issue if lots of unique content permissions are created but there is not a lot of commitment to managing the results.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up a data connection that will allow you to detect the group membership of the user. [Here are the steps](http://www.hishamqaddomi.ca/spg/index.php/sharepoint-2010/infopath-2010/65-checking-if-a-user-is-a-member-in-a-sharepoint-group-within-web-infopath-2010-forms)

Next you will want to create a rule on form load that switches to the desired view based on the group membership.

Comment: Please add more details from the link. If the link breaks now your answer will not be as helpful as it could be!